# How to identify if a particular string/pattern exist in a column using pySpark

Tags: string, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, sql-like

Below is my sample dataframe for household things.

Here **W** represents **Wooden**
**G** represents **Glass** and **P** represents **Plastic**, and different items are classified in that category.
So I want to identify which items falls in **W,G,P** categories. As an initial step ,I tried classifying it for **Chair**

```
M = sqlContext.createDataFrame([('W-Chair-Shelf;G-Vase;P-Cup',''),
                                ('W-Chair',''),
                                ('W-Shelf;G-Cup;P-Chair',''),
                                  ('G-Cup;P-ShowerCap;W-Board','')],
                                 ['Household_chores_arrangements','Chair'])

M.createOrReplaceTempView('M')
+-----------------------------+-----+
|Household_chores_arrangements|Chair|
+-----------------------------+-----+
|   W-Chair-Shelf;G-Vase;P-Cup|     |
|                      W-Chair|     |
|        W-Shelf;G-Cup;P-Chair|     |
|    G-Cup;P-ShowerCap;W-Board|     |
+-----------------------------+-----+
```

I tried to do it for one condition where I can mark it as W, But I am not getting expected results,may be my condition is wrong.

```
df = sqlContext.sql("select * from M where Household_chores_arrangements like '%W%Chair%'")
display(df)
```

Is there a better way to do this in pySpark

Expected output

```
+-----------------------------+-----+
|Household_chores_arrangements|Chair|
+-----------------------------+-----+
|   W-Chair-Shelf;G-Vase;P-Cup|    W|
|                      W-Chair|    W|
|        W-Shelf;G-Cup;P-Chair|    P|
|    G-Cup;P-ShowerCap;W-Board| NULL|
+-----------------------------+-----+
```

Thanks @mck - for the solution.

**Update**
In addition to that I was trying to analyse more on regexp_extract option.So altered the sample set

```
M = sqlContext.createDataFrame([('Wooden|Chair',''),
                                ('Wooden|Cup;Glass|Chair',''),
                                ('Wooden|Cup;Glass|Showercap;Plastic|Chair','')        ],
                                 ['Household_chores_arrangements','Chair'])
M.createOrReplaceTempView('M')
df = spark.sql("""
    select 
        Household_chores_arrangements, 
        nullif(regexp_extract(Household_chores_arrangements, '(Wooden|Glass|Plastic)(|Chair)', 1), '') as Chair 
    from M
""")
display(df)
```

Result:

```
+-----------------------------+-----------------+
|Household_chores_arrangements|            Chair|
+-----------------------------+-----------------+
|                 Wooden|Chair           |Wooden|
|       Wooden|Cup;Glass|Chair           |Wooden|
|Wooden|Cup;Glass|Showercap;Plastic|Chair|Wooden|
+-----------------------------+----------------+
```

Changed delimiter to | instead of - and made changes in the query aswell. Was expecting results as below, But derived a wrong result

```
+-----------------------------+-----------------+
|Household_chores_arrangements|            Chair|
+-----------------------------+-----------------+
|                 Wooden|Chair           |Wooden|
|       Wooden|Cup;Glass|Chair           |Glass |
|Wooden|Cup;Glass|Showercap;Plastic|Chair|Plastic|
+-----------------------------+----------------+
```

If delimiter alone is changed,should we need to change any other values?

**update - 2**

I have got the solution for the above mentioned **update**.

For pipe delimiter we have to escape them using 4 \

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `regexp_extract` to extract the categories, and if no match is found, replace empty string with null using `nullif`.

```
df = spark.sql("""
    select 
        Household_chores_arrangements, 
        nullif(regexp_extract(Household_chores_arrangements, '([A-Z])-Chair', 1), '') as Chair 
    from M
""")

df.show(truncate=False)
+-----------------------------+-----+
|Household_chores_arrangements|Chair|
+-----------------------------+-----+
|W-Chair-Shelf;G-Vase;P-Cup   |W    |
|W-Chair                      |W    |
|W-Shelf;G-Cup;P-Chair        |P    |
|G-Cup;P-ShowerCap;W-Board    |null |
+-----------------------------+-----+
```

Comment: ok!!! But if it was Wooden instead of W in household_chores_arrangements,do we need to change them to approx index?

Comment: Then you need to change the regex pattern to, e.g. `'(Wooden|Glass|Plastic)-Chair'`

Comment: So in regexp_extract- 1 indicates noting but the group value/number that needs to be picked as a result. and -chair is the one we are going to match.- indicates the delimiter in sample data.Hope I am right..Also this worked well with this example,while investigating more one regexp_extract I tried to replace - with | in sample data aswell as  the query,but it didnt give me the expected result.Let me see if I can post an update in the same question

Comment: I got the solution for | delimiter we have to use 4 escape (Wooden|Glass|Plastic)(\\\\|Chair)

Comment: yes, | is a special regex character that needs to be escaped.